# How much of code can I copy from an open source program?

Tags: php, open-source, licensing

I am building a CMS for a client, and I needed some inspiration from Drupal, Joomla!, and Wordpress.  Now that I have the whole think in my mind, I typed out some of the code and it looks extremely similar to that of Joomla!.  I don't want to be stealing their source code, but I want to be able to call it my own.

Is using the same methods (same ways of doing things, but written in different ways) okay?  Where is the line of plagerism when it comes to programming?

edit: Lets just say, for the sake of this question, I wish to sell this CMS and generate money from it.

Comment: You should consult a lawyer as to questions of the law.

Comment: This isn't a school project or a research paper, you don't have to worry about plagiarism. You can plagiarize all you want, it may be dishonest, but it's not illegal. (Of course, don't infringe anyone's copyrights.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the license. Most Open Source programs, you can 'steal' all the code as long as you copy the licence(generally MIT or GPL).
That's the whole point of opensource. Plagiarism is relative to the author's wishes. If the author says(in the license) its okay to modify his code, its okay to modify his code
Also, if you drop a line of credit about the original authors, its perfectly fine

Comment: You do have to check if the license is "infectious", like GPL. If you ship code with portions under a certain license, your whole code base may need to follow that license as well (as Linksys/Cisco found out the hard way a few years ago).

Comment: True. if you are writing your own software for sale, it is better to write your own code only getting 'inspired' by the opensource software. 
If its for a client, however, I don't think liscense is that much of an issue since its not really a release

Answer (score 3):

This question is kind of like saying you're writing a paper. To research this paper, you read a book and used the same ideas that you found in the book, but wrote the paper using your own words. Is that plagiarism? Probably. If you're writing your own CMS and borrowing a lot of code from Joomla, I'd consider using Joomla and developing an extension to fit your specific needs. If you can't do that, I'd do one of two things:

1. Use the code, and release your code under a license permitted
2. Get explicit written permission from the developers of Joomla to grant you ownership of the questionable code.

When it comes to issues like these, I think it's always better to be safe than sorry.